# Is there a specific term for non interior points of a set A?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For a set $A$ (a subset of some metric space $X$), the interior points are inside the set (i.e. an open ball around them totally contained within $A$). The boundary points may or may not belong to $A$. We could classify the boundary points into two categories. Those that belong to $A$ and those that don't belong to $A$.  Are there specific names for these categories?

In particular, is there a name for a point $x \in A$ which is not an interior point of $A$? Or should I just call them non-interior points of $A$?

Is there a name for the set $A \setminus \text{int } A$?

Comment: I would say "$x$ is in the compliment of $A$." Exterior point is typically reserved for points that are in the compliment of the closure of $A$. This allows us to identify every point as interior, boundary, or exterior points.

Comment: Yes, exterior points are not inside $A$. They are the interior of $X \setminus A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$ is called (by some, it’s not common) the *frontier* of $A$ (denoted $\text{Fr}(A)$). It can also be written as $\partial A\cap A$ where $\partial A$ is the (usual) boundary of $A$. For closed sets these sets (frontier and boundary) coincide.